# WWW-Authenticate Header CSRF Issue

Tags: php, security, http-headers, csrf, www-authenticate

I've heard from a friend that the `WWW-Authenticate` header can be explicitly defined within a malicious php file on a remote server and use an image mimetype e.g. `image/jpeg` or `image/png`.

***Hypothetical Situation***

Say this file is `malicious.com/image.php` and I add this image to my forum signature on some arbitrary forum. Specifically, `gaiaonline.com`. When another visitor visits a thread with my post on it, they'll see the login prompt given by the `WWW-Authenticate` header. After the visitor/victim has input their username/password, the hacker can store it on their remote server, email it to themselves, etc.

Malicious code: `<img src="malicious.com/image.php" />` containing `WWW-Authenticate` header. Can be input through standard posting/BBcode.

How can this be fixed? *I would think that a cross-domain access is available for this*.

Comment: I'd consider this more phishing than CSRF.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I would think that browsers should handle this issue themselves; otherwise, there should be a way to disallow headers based on the domain. If neither of these options available, wouldn't this be a fatal flaw of the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be "fixed" except by disallowing any external images (e.g. by proxying them through your server so users never hit the real URL).

Comment: In addition to this, I would say this is also a browser user interface issue. Browsers could perhaps specifically warn the user that an embedded image from a different origin requests basic auth.